# How can I debug a Discord icon being sometimes missing from the Xfce panel?

Tags: linux, xfce, xubuntu, ubuntu-22.04, discord

On Xubuntu 22.04, I use the Discord snap. Its small icon is sometimes missing from my panel and sometimes not. I am unsure if it is supposed to live in the Indicator plugin or in the the Status Tray Icons; The settings menu for those never seem to show it. Restarting the panel never seems to fix the issue of the icon not showing on the panel. It seems to be fixed only by reboots.

Here is some relevant terminal output. The following is an example from when the icon has failed to appear.

```bash
~$ PANEL_DEBUG=1 xfce4-panel
xfce4-panel(main): version 4.16.3 on gtk+ 3.24.33 (3.24.29), glib 2.72.4 (2.68.3)
xfce4-panel(module-factory): reading /usr/share/xfce4/panel/plugins
xfce4-panel(application): found window manager after 1 tries
xfce4-panel(base-window): 0x564b8f52ff30: rgba visual=0x564b8f4fad90, compositing=true
xfce4-panel(base-window): 0x564b8f52ff30: rgba visual=0x564b8f4fad90, compositing=true
xfce4-panel(display-layout): 0x564b8f52ff30: display=:0.0{comp=true}, screen-0[0x564b8f4ee020]=[3520,1080] (eDP1=[0,180;1600,900], HDMI2=[1600,0;1920,1080])
xfce4-panel(positioning): 0x564b8f52ff30: screen=0x564b8f4ee020, monitors=2, output-name=(null), span-monitors=false, base=720,11
xfce4-panel(positioning): 0x564b8f52ff30: working-area: screen=0x564b8f4ee020, x=0, y=180, w=1600, h=900
xfce4-panel(struts): 0x564b8f52ff30: top=201, start_x=0, end_x=1599
xfce4-panel(external): register dbus path /org/xfce/Panel/Wrapper/1
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=external-wrapper, name=whiskermenu, id=1)
xfce4-panel(external): whiskermenu-1: child spawned; pid=8657, argc=7
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=object-type, name=launcher, id=13)
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=object-type, name=launcher, id=15)
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=object-type, name=launcher, id=14)
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=object-type, name=directorymenu, id=18)
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=object-type, name=tasklist, id=3)
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=object-type, name=separator, id=4)
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=object-type, name=clock, id=12)
xfce4-panel(external): register dbus path /org/xfce/Panel/Wrapper/6
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=external-wrapper, name=notification-plugin, id=6)
xfce4-panel(external): notification-plugin-6: child spawned; pid=8658, argc=7
xfce4-panel(external): register dbus path /org/xfce/Panel/Wrapper/17
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=external-wrapper, name=systray, id=17)
xfce4-panel(external): systray-17: child spawned; pid=8659, argc=7
xfce4-panel(external): register dbus path /org/xfce/Panel/Wrapper/2
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=external-wrapper, name=indicator, id=2)
xfce4-panel(external): indicator-2: child spawned; pid=8660, argc=7
xfce4-panel(external): register dbus path /org/xfce/Panel/Wrapper/9
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=external-wrapper, name=power-manager-plugin, id=9)
xfce4-panel(external): power-manager-plugin-9: child spawned; pid=8661, argc=7
xfce4-panel(external): register dbus path /org/xfce/Panel/Wrapper/10
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=external-wrapper, name=pulseaudio, id=10)
xfce4-panel(external): pulseaudio-10: child spawned; pid=8662, argc=7
xfce4-panel(external): register dbus path /org/xfce/Panel/Wrapper/16
xfce4-panel(module): new item (type=external-wrapper, name=xfce4-clipman-plugin, id=16)
xfce4-panel(external): xfce4-clipman-plugin-16: child spawned; pid=8665, argc=7
xfce4-panel(external): systray-17: child is embedded; 7 properties in queue
xfce4-panel(systray): rgba visual is 0x560cb9491590
xfce4-panel(systray): registered manager on screen 0
xfce4-panel(external): whiskermenu-1: child is embedded; 7 properties in queue
xfce4-panel(external): pulseaudio-10: child is embedded; 7 properties in queue
xfce4-panel(external): power-manager-plugin-9: child is embedded; 7 properties in queue
xfce4-panel(external): indicator-2: child is embedded; 7 properties in queue
xfce4-panel(external): xfce4-clipman-plugin-16: child is embedded; 7 properties in queue
xfce4-panel(external): notification-plugin-6: child is embedded; 7 properties in queue

(wrapper-2.0:8658): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:00:12.357: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkToggleButton to a container of type XfcePanelPlugin, but the widget is already inside a container of type XfcePanelPlugin, please remove the widget from its existing container first.

(wrapper-2.0:8660): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:00:12.430: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:46: The style property GtkWidget:focus-padding is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version

(wrapper-2.0:8660): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:00:12.430: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:78: The style property GtkWidget:focus-line-width is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version

(wrapper-2.0:8660): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:00:12.430: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:108: The style property GtkButton:default-border is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version

(wrapper-2.0:8660): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:00:12.430: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:136: The style property GtkButton:inner-border is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version

(wrapper-2.0:8662): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:00:12.431: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2) while allocating gadget (node button, owner PulseaudioButton)

(wrapper-2.0:8657): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:00:12.464: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkToggleButton)

(wrapper-2.0:8658): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:00:12.467: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkToggleButton)

(wrapper-2.0:8665): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:00:12.485: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkToggleButton)

(wrapper-2.0:8661): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:00:12.532: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2) while allocating gadget (node button, owner PowerManagerButton)
```

Upon opening Discord from the Whisker menu, the above outputs appear from the same command

```bash
Discord 0.0.26
[8716:0418/090018.625660:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(273)] Failed to adjust OOM score of renderer with pid 8837: Permission denied (13)
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open i965: /snap/discord/151/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /snap/discord/151/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
Starting app.
Starting updater.
2023-04-18T08:00:18.641Z [Modules] Modules initializing
2023-04-18T08:00:18.641Z [Modules] Distribution: remote
2023-04-18T08:00:18.641Z [Modules] Host updates: disabled
2023-04-18T08:00:18.641Z [Modules] Module updates: enabled
2023-04-18T08:00:18.641Z [Modules] Module install path: /home/[my-user-name]/snap/discord/151/.config/discord/0.0.26/modules
2023-04-18T08:00:18.641Z [Modules] Module installed file path: /home/[my-user-name]/snap/discord/151/.config/discord/0.0.26/modules/installed.json
2023-04-18T08:00:18.642Z [Modules] Module download path: /home/[my-user-name]/snap/discord/151/.config/discord/0.0.26/modules/pending
[8837:0418/090018.704384:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(186)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[8716:0418/090018.713061:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(273)] Failed to adjust OOM score of renderer with pid 8874: Permission denied (13)
[8874:0418/090018.738772:ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported.
[8846:0418/090018.811681:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(128)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.
2023-04-18T08:00:18.852Z [Modules] No updates to install
2023-04-18T08:00:18.859Z [Modules] Host is up to date.
2023-04-18T08:00:18.866Z [Modules] Checking for module updates at https://discord.com/api/modules/stable/versions.json
2023-04-18T08:00:19.055Z [Modules] No module updates available.
Optional module ./ElectronTestRpc was not included.
[8716:0418/090019.221117:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(623)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Inhibit: object_path= /org/freedesktop/login1: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.147" (uid=1000 pid=8716 comm="/snap/discord/151/usr/share/discord/Discord --use-" label="snap.discord.discord (enforce)") interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="Inhibit" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.login1" (uid=0 pid=1014 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind " label="unconfined")
WEIGHT /home/[my-user-name]/snap/discord/151/.config/discord/0.0.26/modules/discord_krisp/NC_small_8k.thw
WEIGHT /home/[my-user-name]/snap/discord/151/.config/discord/0.0.26/modules/discord_krisp/NC_small_16k.thw
WEIGHT /home/[my-user-name]/snap/discord/151/.config/discord/0.0.26/modules/discord_krisp/c6.f.s.ced125.thw
WEIGHT /home/[my-user-name]/snap/discord/151/.config/discord/0.0.26/modules/discord_krisp/VAD_weight.thw
2023-04-18T08:00:21.698Z [Modules] Host is up to date.
2023-04-18T08:00:21.698Z [Modules] Checking for module updates at https://discord.com/api/modules/stable/versions.json
2023-04-18T08:00:21.701Z [Modules] No module updates available.
```

How can I begin to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have come up against
[[Bug] icons do not reliably show up in systray](https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/-/issues/599).

The conclusion there was that this was a conflict with
ayatana-indicator-application.

There was also a script included for restarting xfce4-panel, which for some
people resolved to problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Optionally sleep before restarting panel
sleep ${1:-0}
xfce4-panel -q
xfce4-panel &
```

Comment: No luck with the script, but thanks.

Comment: Disabling ayatana-indicator-application appears to fix the problem. The only issue is that I have no idea what ayatana-indicator-application actually does in Xubuntu. My general impression is that it comes upstream from Debian.

Comment: The [ayatana-indicator-application](https://github.com/AyatanaIndicators/ayatana-indicator-application) is described as: "menu indicator for Unity7 and optionally for others, e.g. MATE, XFCE, LXDE). The indicator takes menus from applications and places them into the panel".